# How to write Azure Cosmos DB SQL-API count distinct query without non-deterministic results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**My Aim**

I would like to count the number of distinct values of `FileName` for Azure Cosmos DB documents like the following in a single partition, using the SQL API.

```json
{
    "id": "some uuid",
    "FileName": "file-1.txt",
    "PartitionKeyField": "some key",
    ... other fields ...
}
```

**My Test**

I have uploaded 533,956 documents with 500,000 different `FileName` values, i.e. 33,956 documents have duplicate `FileName` (other fields are different). These are all uploaded with the same `PartitionKeyField`.

(I can only reproduce the behaviour below for 100,000s of documents).

I would like to count the number of distinct `FileName` values - so hope to get back 500,000.

**Attempt 0 - Sanity Check**

If I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.FileName 
FROM c 
WHERE c.PartitionKeyField = 'some key'
```

This returns 500,000 documents as expected.

**Attempt 1**

However, I don't need all the documents, I just need the count, so I try to run the following query

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.FileName 
    FROM c 
    WHERE c.PartitionKeyField = 'some key'
) c2
```

But this gives 533,956 - i.e. it's as if `DISTINCT` has not been applied.

**Attempt 2**

Next I tried the following, **redundant** `GROUP BY` in an attempt to force the count to work:

```sql
SELECT c2.PartitionKeyField, COUNT(1) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.FileName 
    FROM c
    WHERE c.PartitionKeyField = 'some key'
) c2 
GROUP BY c2.PartitionKeyField
```

The result returned by this depends on how many RUs is allocated to the collection, e.g.

- Returns 500,007 at 9900 RUs
- Returns 500,175 at 5000 RUs
- Returns 500,441 at 3000 RUs
- Returns 500,812 at 1000 RUs
- Returns 501,406 at 400 RUs

Also, the above values are averages, e.g. for 9900 RUs results of 500,009 and 500,006 were also returned.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to write the required "count" query in a deterministic way that doesn't depend on the number of RUs? (other than retrieving all documents as in **Attempt 0**?)
- Why does increasing the number of RUs change the result of the query in **Attempt 2**?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this SQL:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(c2)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.FileName 
    FROM c 
    WHERE c.PartitionKeyField = 'some key'
) c2
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately this still gives incorrect result, e.g. 500523

Comment: How about this SQL?`SELECT VALUE COUNT(c2)
FROM (
    SELECT c.FileName 
    FROM c 
    WHERE c.PartitionKeyField = 'some key'
    GROUP BY c.FileName
) c2`

Comment: I found a [blog](https://spzsource.github.io/azure/2019/11/30/cosoms-db-distinct-count.html) about this. It is a bug.

Comment: It's not a bug, although I have not bee able to find an answer to this same question.    According to the information given here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-keywords , you will find that

Queries with an aggregate system function and a subquery with DISTINCT are not supported. For example, the following query is not supported:

SQL

Copy
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT f.lastName FROM f)

What the documentation does not say is how to get the distinct count.